# After Angular ng build --prod, all image on home page are not displayed

Tags: html, angular

I am working on an angular webpage. When I am using ng start, all the images on my home pages are successfully being displayed and visible. I build my angular project again with ng build --prod. I know that this --prod flag minimizes the filesize but when I deployed to the IIS web server, I don't see any of the images on the home page.

Even with the minimize file, I can still see the image with the ng start but not with IIS.

In my HTML file, I reference the image with code like this

All of my images are located inside a folder call assets/img. The following shows my IIS folder content.

[image]

Have anyone else have this issue? Any help is greatly appreciated.

The minimized files works with Angular 6 when start with the command line ng start. When I copied the files to the IIS folder, there are no display images. I am wondering if there is something I need to set on IIS. I checked and the Static Content is set under Internet Information Services. I also copied and pasted all the images in the folder and each of the subfolder but still no images are displayed.

Thanks

Comment: So are you getting 404 errors in the browser developer tools? What path is it trying to load the images from, and what path should it use?

Comment: Hi, Yes, I just checked and I am getting the following error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: I am using this image path: src="../assets/img/prettyPicture.png. All the images are found in the assets/img folder

Comment: ../ wil look in the parent folder for assets

Comment: Also tried /assets/img but still no luck

Comment: @JohnYee can you check the image folder name is `img` or `image` or `images`? I believe you should refer to images folder path with `/assets/{Image folder name}/`

Comment: it is  /assets/img.

Comment: try finding your assets via you-server/whereever/assets/might/be, ex if I am running locally, localhost:8080/assets/images/firstImage.jpg -- see if anything popups and then update path accordingly.

Comment: Which version of angular did you use? Try to build with `ng build --prod --base-href .`